# Migration from .Net to PHP

Tags: php, asp.net

I have a code written using ASP.NET and I want to convert it to PHP whithout having to rewrite the code. Is there a free converting tool to assist in converting ?

Comment: LOL `Is there a free converting tool to assist in converting ?` - I honestly hope not. Why would you do that? PHP is useless compared to ASP.Net. Also, your question is completely off topic in StackOverflow.

Comment: @HighCore How can you say that _PHP is useless compared to ASP.Net_

Comment: @Manohar how is it not? whatever PHP does, ASP.Net does a million times better, faster, and without stupid incomprehensible errors or blank pages.

Comment: tanx @HighCore . and PHP has its own advantage

Comment: @SR1 `and PHP has its own advantage` -  no it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

No there no such tool. The kind tool you are talking is called transcompiler.

> A type of compiler that takes the source code of a programming
>   language as its input and outputs the source code into another
>   programming language.

You can design such kind of tool. Facebook developed [HipHop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP) to convert PHP to C++.

ASP.NET is framework on top of C# so it may be more difficult to have such kind of tool you are asking about.